# Comparing a folder with a git repository's subfolder

Tags: git

I have a folder `now` once exported from a git repository, and the git repository itself:

```
/
/now/
/repository.git/
```

I'd like to compare the files in `now` to the current state of the repository. While this is easily done with `--git-dir=/repository.git` and `--work-tree=/now`,

```
git --git-dir=/repository.git --work-tree=/now status
```

it is not so obvious to me, when `now` was a **subfolder** of the stuff in the git repository.

Is there a way—besides checking out the repository again and `diff`ing the stuff—to have `git` somehow compare the folder and the corresponding subfolder in the repository? (I know, that git is not centered around the idea of changes in single files, therefore I actually expect a well-informed *no*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate a temporary index file with just the contents of the subdirectory of the repository and then diff the existing files against it.

```
diff-sub() { : usage: diff-sub repo treeish-in-repo external-dir
  (
    GIT_DIR="$1" GIT_WORK_TREE="$3"
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/.git-index--now-sub.tmp
    if test -e "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"; then
      echo "already exists: $GIT_INDEX_FILE"
      exit 1
    fi
    export GIT_DIR GIT_INDEX_FILE GIT_WORK_TREE
    git read-tree "$2" &&
    git diff
    ec=$?
    rm -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
    exit "$ec"
  )
}
: diff sub from master in /repository.git against /now
diff-sub /repository.git master:sub /now
```

Note: If you run other Git commands that compare against the normal, full tree (e.g. `git status` or `git diff --cached` instead of `git diff`), then you will see odd-looking results since both the index and the working tree only contain a portion of the normal, full tree.

Comment: Hm, interesting idea. How do you get the temporary index file? I looked at stuff like `git-read-tree` and the format of the index file itself, but I haven't figured out yet apart from editing the binary file.

Comment: You should only use Git commands to read/update a Git index file (i.e. you should not need to know about the binary, on-disk format unless you are writing your own “plumbing” command). When the GIT_INDEX_FILE environment variable is set, all Git commands will use the specified file instead of the normal index file (usually `.git/index`). In the case of the shell code in the answer, the `git read-tree` command will create the alternate index file and the `git diff` command will read it and compare it’s effective contents to the specified working tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the directory structure leading to the subfolder and take advantage of the `--relative` option to commands such as `diff` and `log` (but not `status`). For example, if you have a checkout of `sub/dir`:

```
mkdir -p sub
mv now sub/dir
git --git-dir=/repository.git diff --relative=sub/dir
```

Comment: +1, thanks. I assume it's not possible without the `mv`?

Comment: @Boldewyn: not that I know of, but I'm a git newbie. If moving is a problem, maybe you can use `cp -al` (copy directories hard-linking files) or [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/).

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing me to bindfs (I really start to love the power of FUSE...).